# Can you save white from checkmate?

Tags: checkmate

Is white able to recover/win this game after these moves?
[image]

And then black takes the bishop:

[image]

White resigned after this, what would you do?

Comment: You sure white resigned? It's forced mate for White. Black should resign.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off: I suspect White resigned due to the material disadvantage rather than some immediate mating threat. Having said that, I don't see any reason not to give check on c8 and try to setup some threats here as White, since it seems like Black gets checkmated:

1.Qc8+, Ke7 2.Rb7+, Kf6 3.Qf5+, Kg7 4.Qxf7+, Kh6 5.Qg7#

Comment: Did you figure this out by yourself? Impressive!

Comment: @Habbo it was the first line I looked at. It's simple to spot if you're used to prioritizing looking for checks when calculating variations; it then follows naturally, since every move White makes in that sequence is a check, and Black has only one reasonable reply at every move in the sequence.

Comment: @Habbo Scrounged probably suspected a mate within 2 seconds (literally) and had it worked out in 10. You'll learn the themes. First and foremost, Black's K is undefended and White's Queen can make a strong check. And White can then activate a rook with check. White's advanced pawns (`e4` and `d5`) protect vital squares and allow a Queen or rook to land there.  Black's pawn on `f7` is notoriously weak in all cases, and with the rook on `b7` it's already under attack.

Comment: @Habbo: it's not as if there are any other reasonable options. White's a rook behind, he needs something serious, so let's try the checks. It's hard not to figure it out then.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the board I can speculate that both players are at almost beginner level. I do not see any reason why White should resign because Black does not have any forced checks. It is the middle game and both Black's knights are at the back rank, undeveloped. Any opening, you let knights get developed first within 5-7 moves. In fact this kind of position does not even need any concrete calculations because Black's queen alone cannot do anything. Here White should have attempted at least the checks shown in the above variation, and if he would have run out of checks, then I can understand the situation, else Black should resign here.